# Can we use `const_cast` to modify a constant variable?

Tags: c++, compiler-optimization, volatile, const-cast

```
int main()
{
    const int ia = 10;

    int *pia = const_cast<int*>(&ia);
    *pia = 5;

    std::cout << &ia << "\t" <<  pia <<endl;
    std::cout <<  ia << "\t" << *pia <<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
0x28fef4       0x28fef4
10             5
```

`*pia` and `ia` have the same address, but they have different values. My purpose is to use `const_cast` to modify a constant value, but as the result shows that it does not work.

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 9):

The reason why you see `10` printed for `ia` is most likely the compiler optimization: it sees a `const` object, decides that it's not going to change, and replaces the last printout with this:

```
cout<< 10 <<"  "<<*ppa<<endl;
```

In other words, the generated code has the value of the `const` "baked into" the binary.

Casting away the const-ness of an object that has originally been declared as `const` and writing to that object is undefined behavior:

> $5.2.11/7 - Note: Depending on the type of the object, a write operation through the pointer, lvalue or pointer to data member resulting from a const_cast that casts away a const-qualifier68) may produce undefined behavior (7.1.5.1).

Depending on the platform, `const` objects may be placed in a protected region of memory, to which you cannot write. Working around the `const`-ness in the type system may help your program compile, but you may see random results or even crashes.

Answer (score 7):

It is undefined behaviour to modify a constant value. Don't do it. If you need to modify the value, don't declare it as `const`.