# Does assignment of the same value to a const variable cause UB in C++?

Tags: c++, constants, undefined-behavior

Given the following C++ Code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const int i = 1;
    *const_cast<int*>(&i) = 1; // Not allowed but doesn't do anything?
    std::cout << i << "\n";
}
```

**Question**: Does the above code invoke UB (undefined behavior)? I know that casting away const and assigning a new value to `i` results in UB, since we are not allowed to change the value of a const variable. However, in the above code, I didn't actually change the value of `i` - so, will this still be UB?

Comment: Suppose an implementation places the `const int i` in read-only memory, but doesn't perform any optimizations. The `*const_cast<int*>(&i) = 1` would try to write to read-only memory. Yes, it is still UB

Comment: There is no low-level "optimisation" that ignores an assignment if the new value is the same as the old; it would take much longer than just doing it.

Comment: @molbdnilo Take: int i = 0; i = 0; which should be easily simplified by an optimizer to int i = 0; How exactly is the second version taking much longer than the first?

Comment: @Justin Thanks, thats a good point.

Comment: There was no need to reopen this. There are more than 100 duplicates for this. Some dupes: [Two different values at the same memory address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593687/two-different-values-at-the-same-memory-address) and [Can we use `const_cast` to modify a constant variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19208560/can-we-use-const-cast-to-modify-a-constant-variable)

Comment: @user12002570 These questions are different, as they ask about actually modifying the constant value while this question asks about the usecase that the actual value is not modified (as explicitly explained in the edit). So no duplicate.

Comment: ;@SampleTime No, the answer of the dupe still applies to this question. So this is a dupe. "Any attempt" means any.

Comment: @user12002570 Its not obvious that it applies to this specific case as well, which was why the question was asked in the first place. It might be obvious to you, but the answers in the linked questions do not explicitly state this. So in my opinion, it is not a dupe.

Comment: @user12002570 It is also not clear whether this speicific usecase even counts as "attempt". That was also the reason for my comment on the accepted answer, which then resolved the question.

Comment: @SampleTime In that case, I don't think the accepted answer actually answers the question. In particular, [expr.const.cast](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const.cast#6) is what you're looking for. I've added an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77967027/12002570).

Comment: @SampleTime Bascially, as long as you do a write operation on the const object(which you do here), you'll have UB as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77967027/12002570)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> will this still be UB?

Yes it is UB. To see this, we first move onto [expr.ass#2](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.ass#2) which means that even though you're assigning the same value to `i`, it **still constitutes a modification**. From [expr.ass#2]:

> In simple assignment (=), **the object referred to by the left operand is modified** ([defns.access]) by replacing its value with the result of the right operand.

Now we move onto [dcl.dcl](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.dcl#dcl.type.cv-4.sentence-2) that makes the program UB:

> **Any attempt to modify** ([expr.ass], [expr.post.incr], [expr.pre.incr]) **a const object** ([basic.type.qualifier]) during its lifetime ([basic.life]) results in undefined behavior.

So as the assignment constitutes a modification(expr.ass#2), the program has undefined behavior.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. It's still UB.

*Attempting* to change a const variable is UB, not just assigning a *new* value.

From N4296, Section 1.9, Paragraph 4:

> Certain other operations are described in this International Standard as undefined (for example, the effect of **attempting** to modify a `const` object).

Comment: I know that paragraph of the standard, but for me it doesn't really resolve the question. For me, "modification" implies that something is changed. If nothing is changed anyway, I can also see no attempt. Does the standard define anywhere what "modify" means exactly?

Comment: @SampleTime Nope, but attempting to *write* to the storage of a const object *is* modification - the value doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

> Question: Does the above code invoke UB (undefined behavior)?

Yes.

> However, in the above code, I didn't actually change the value of i

That's **exactly** what you did when you assigned to the result of indirection through the pointer that pointed to `i`.

It's just that because it is undefined, there is no guarantee that the program would behave in the way that you would expect for a program to behave when you assign a value.

Answer (score 0):

`const_cast` is for when you have a const reference to a variable that *isn't* `const`. Basically it's a way to cheat if you *know* that you're referencing a non-const object. I think a "good" (honestly, I never think it's actually good) example of `const_cast` is for when you have an internal structure that modifies itself normally, but presents itself as `const` when accessed from the outside (a way to make things appear read-only from the outside).

If you try to modify actual data declared as const, then it's undefined, and depending on what system you're working on will change the error. Some environments might trigger a segfault, some will do nothing (read-only memory with ignored writes), and some might change the data anyway (for example, if a program's data is entirely loaded into normal, writable memory).

Comment: "when you have an internal structure that modifies itself normally, but presents itself as const" - in such a case the member variable should be marked `mutable` and the acessor function can then still be `const`.

Comment: My explanation probably isn't super clear but I think mutable is a fairly different use case (and arguably a much better example than what I wrote, for the use of const_cast). What I had in mind is completely non-const data that's returned as const through a getter function, and something that 'gets' the data, on the internal side, can cheat and modify things through `const_cast` - it's dirty, and I'd totally avoid it, but you never know when that might just be the little hack you need.